# Plot options don't work in Variable Radius Pie chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

Hí I'm trying to use VARIABLE-RADIUS-PIE SERIES from Highcharts https://www.highcharts.com/demo/variable-radius-pie/gray.

It works well, display the chart as pretended. But I want to hide the labels, for example in this example I want the country name to disappear and only show in the tooltip. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfpkE.png)

I'm trying to use enable the datalabels like this

```js
plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
          },
        }
      }
```

But don't work, I think is because of the type of chart. 
Any suggestions, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a simple mistake. Instead of `plotOptions.pie.dataLabels` you should set `plotOptions.variablepie.dataLabels` or just `plotOptions.series.dataLabels`. Also note, that to disable labels **dataLabels.enabled** property has to be **false**.

**Code:**

```
plotOptions: {
  variablepie: {
    allowPointSelect: true,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aLqcwsux/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.variablepie.dataLabels

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works with your suggestion @Wojciech Chmiel